# Why are WPF animation applied to all Controls of same type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, coloranimation

I'm currently trying to animate some `Border` element in my WPF application.

I need to change `Background` property and I'm using `ColorAnimation` class with this helper method:

```
public static void AnimateColor(SolidColorBrush to, Animatable fe)
{
    ColorAnimation ca = new()
    {
        To = to.Color,
        Duration = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)),
    };
    fe.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, ca);
}
```

And I use the method as follow:

```
AnimateColor(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), target.Background);
```

*target* is the control I want to animate.

However, when I run the code, *all instances* of the same control type are animated, e.g. all my `Border` elements in current Window are being animated.

What am I missing here? How do I animate a *single* instance of Control from code-behind?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit, solved by accepted answer**

I'm updating my answer so that anyone who is stuck with this "issue" could understand it by first understanding how WPF handle animations.

As suggested by accepted answer, I was setting an initial value to each border background as follow:

```
SolidColorBrush initialBackground = new(Colors.White);
border1.Background = initialBackground; 
border2.Background = initialBackground; 
border3.Background = initialBackground;
```

I thought an animation would work on the Control, but this was my error.
Now I understood than a WPF `ColorAnimation` works on the specific value assigned to the DependecyProperty being animated, so in my case, I was animating always the same instance initialBackground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controls use a single shared Background Brush, of which you animate the Color property.

Assign a separate SolidColorBrush to each control that should be animated:

```
<Border x:Name="target">
    <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. I don't think this control could be animated because its Background would be a frozen / sealed object. Also, I need to handle this animation from C# code instead of XAML.

Comment: @IFrank Did you notice the edited answer? If you explictly assign a SolidColorBrush to the Background (in XAML or in code behind) you can animate its Color separately.

Comment: Oh now I understood, thank you. Also I was setting the same instance of SolidColorBrush to each border, so I guess that was my error. Setting an initial background value for each Border (from C# code) solved the problem. Animations seems to require a bit more deep understanding of WPF inside mechanisms. Thank you!

Comment: This is just simple object oriented programming. Multiple objects use a single other object as value of one of their properties. If you change a property of that single object via one of the objects that use it, all others are affected.

Comment: I agree, but I thought WPF would animate the control itself - not the SolidColorBrush assigned to backgrounds. Now it's clear indeed.

Comment: Sure, you are calling `target.Background.BeginAnimation(...)`, not `target.BeginAnimation(...)`.